# How to set up desktop shortcuts in KDE to run terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, kde, .desktop

I am trying to make a desktop shortcut to launch `Spyder`, which can be launched by typing `spyder` in terminal.

I made a `spy.sh` script with `spyder` in it. It works with `bash spy.sh` and `./spy.sh`. But when I make a desktop shortcut like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=spyd
Exec=/Desktop/spy.sh
Comment=
Icon=
Type=Application
Terminal=true
```

It gives out an error:

> "There was an error creating child process for the terminal. Failed to
>   execute child process “/Desktop/spy.sh” (No such file or directory)"

Same error when I change into `Exec=spyder`

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a script to do that, in a terminal just do

```
$ which spyder
```

This gives you the full path to the file that's executed, I suppose `/usr/bin/spyder`. Then just use that path for your `Exec=` line.

```
Exec=/usr/bin/spyder
```

Answer (score 7):

To configure KDE desktop shortcut to run specific command, you have to link the full path of the application.

i.e. use `Exec=/home/(user)/Desktop/spy.sh` instead of `Exec=/Desktop/spy.sh` (Because if you type `/Desktop/spy.sh` the system will actually find files from `/` --> `/Desktop`, which this folder will probably never exist.)

And for runing `Spyder`, follow dessert's answer.

Also, make sure `spy.sh` is executable, or else `Permission denied` will appear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even though linking full path helped remove the error, I couldn't run spyder successfully, a program would come up in taskbar called "web browser" and close. Following dessert's answer did the work.

Comment: You probably have a corrupted `spy.sh` script. Also, if you find an answer working, mark the answer accepted by clicking the checkmark icon.

Comment: But it works when executed from terminal. BTW, why doesn't just writing spyder in Exec= work for me? (suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771849/how-to-set-up-different-desktop-launchers-for-anaconda-spyder-using-conda-enviro)

Comment: Because the desktop environment won't automatically search for `spyder` for you. If you type `export` you will see something like `PATH=/usr/bin...` but KDE desktop won't check this parameter.

Comment: Oh, so this is KDE specific and we can not run commands without making a script? Thanks!

Comment: Not really, most desktop environment won't do that as well.

Comment: @AlekhKarkadaAshok I consider the automatic path completion a terminal feature, it's a good idea to give the full path everywhere else, especially in config files.